# How to plug 2 5m RGB LED light strips together?

Tags: led, led-strip

I got two 5 meters RGB LED light strips and would like to connect them together, controlling them as a single strip.

Each strip power is 72 W, the input voltage is 12V, it has 300 5050 SMD LED emitters and the manual says it needs 6A of current. The controller that came with each fits that same spec.

What should I do to achieve it? Each strip comes with a controller and a remote. Should I get another controller big enough or an amplifier maybe?

This is the product: http://dx.com/p/jr-5050-waterproof-72w-4500lm-300-5050-smd-led-rgb-light-strip-w-remote-controller-12v-175950

Comment: What does the remote do? Is it an infrared beam to switch the LEDs off? Will one remote work both controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These strips are usually arranged in numerous parallel segments of a few series LEDs. The RGB strips can be a little different, but they work basically the same way. It looks like your strip is analog control and not digital (which would have little ICs in the strip to control individual LED color), so the specific color ground lines are all in parallel. You should be able to connect numerous strips in parallel - 12V to 12V, red to red, green to green, and blue to blue to blue. That is the same reason you can cut the strips into smaller segments if you want.

There is a limit to how much current can flow through the strip itself, which varies between manufacturers. Your other limit to how many strips can be connected together is how much power your supply / remote controller can handle. It should specify a limit in watts / current or total number of LEDs or parallel segments. That information should be on a sticker on the power supply or be listed in the manual.

From your product page:

> Power     72 W

Which is 6A at 12V DC. That means your power supply/controller has to be able to handle at least 144 W (12A @ 12V DC) to connect two strips in parallel. Although, it is never a good idea to run something long term near its maximum ratings, so the supply should really be rated for something closer to 200 W.

If you are able to power multiple strips from your supply, it would be best to power them with a star topology so the current for each strip is separated. For example, connecting Christmas lights together end to end is daisy chaining, and the current for every light strand has to flow through the strands before it. Powering multiple light strands from one power strip is more of a star topology, with the current to each strip only flowing through itself (think of the power strip as your power supply).

Comment: Bit lost in the answer. Bases on the product specs. Can I connect end to beginning 2 strips and will it work?

Comment: It can work, but that depends on your power supply's capabilities. I am pretty sure I said that in my answer... "End to beginning" sounds like you want to put two strips in series.

Answer (score 0):

There are devices called "RGB amplifiers" designed to do just what you are looking for, you run the input in parallel with the exist strip and your new strip off its output.